# Exception specification when overriding a virtual function

Tags: c++, exception, virtual-functions, exception-specification

Consider the following code:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void f() throw ( int ) { }
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    void f() throw ( int, double ) { }
};
```

When compiled, it says that derived class B has a looser throw specifier compared to A. What is the importance of this? If we try to exchange their exception specification, such that A::f() throws int and double while B::f() throws only int, the error does not appear.

Comment: I sincerely hope you never throw instances of classes that are not meant to be used as exceptions and this is merely for a quick and dirty illustration of your question :)

Comment: Matthieu: Ah, yes of course. I understand.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. [Don't use exception specifications in C++.](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm) It's very counter-intuitive compared to, say, Java's ones.
2. Having a wider specification in the derived class breaks LSP (Liskov Substitution Principle).

To expand on point 2: `A`'s callers expect that only `int` comes out, but if you use a `B` (which, because it's publicly derived from `A`, also means it's usable as an `A`), suddenly `double` can come out too, and that would break `A`'s contract (that only `int` gets thrown).

Comment: For Herb Sutter's take on this (which agrees with Chris's), see http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm

Comment: In fact, C++ even checks for this in implicit function declarations (for functions it directly calls from those, their exception spec includes the called function's specs): `struct A { virtual ~A() throw(); }; struct B { ~B() throw(int); }; struct C : A, B { }; /* error: ~C() has throw(int), but ~A() has throw()! */`

Comment: @Neil: Thanks for the link; I've changed my link (originally a GotW one) to use it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your B violates the Liskov Substitution Principle - eg:

```
void foo(A* a) throw() // ie I will not throw
{
  try
  {
     a->f();
  }
  catch(int)
  {}
}
```

This is valid according to the interface for A; in particular, we do not expect a double to be thrown. But consider if we were to call

```
foo(new B)
```

with the interface you describe, and

```
B::f()
```

were to throw a double.